# Finding a key-value-pair within a std::multimap with key of type int

Tags: c++, stl, multimap, std-pair

I have a `std::multimap<int, X*>` where `X` is a user-defined type. I want to find a specific key-value-pair within this multimap (i.e. an iterator pointing to this pair).

(A) Complete Example:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

class X {};

int main()
{
    X myX;
    std::multimap<int, X*> myMap;
    auto it = std::find(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), std::make_pair(5, &myX));
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, this does not compile (gcc 12.2.1 with `-std=gnu++2a`):

```
no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘std::pair<const int, X*>’ and ‘const std::pair<int, X*>’)
```

So it seems to me somehow `int` gets converted to `const int`.

(B) Using `std::find_if` with a lamdba function with `const int`, the code compiles:

```
auto it = std::find_if(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), [myX](std::pair<const int, X*>& node){ return 5 == node.first && (&myX) == node.second; } );
```

Questions:

1. Why is the type of the keys in the multimap `const int` and not `int`?
2. How to fix it in a more natural way than using a (complex) lambda function like in (B) or by first looking up by key and then searching within its values (as described by Igor Tandetnik in the comments)?

Comment: The error message tells you why (A) doesn't work. The elements of the map are of type `std::pair<const int, X*>`, but you are trying to compare them with `std::pair<int, X*>`. These are two different types. `auto it = std::find(myMap.begin(), myMap.end(), std::pair<const int, X*>{5, &myX});` should compile. But that's inefficient - it will do a linear scan over the map, rather than utilizing its ability to look up the key in log time. It's best to use `myMap.equal_range(5)` to find a range of all elements with `5` as the key, and then run `find_if` on that range to look for the right value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why is the type of the keys in the multimap const int and not int?

Because the *Key* in all standard maps is immutable.

> How to fix it in a more natural way than using a (complex) lambda function like in (B) or by first looking up by key and then searching within its values?

Here's a simplified example that doesn't use `X*` but `X` in the map:

```cpp
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

struct X {
    bool operator==(const X& rhs) const { return m_value == rhs.m_value; }

    int m_value;
};

int main() {
    std::multimap<int, X> myMap{
        {4, {1}}, {5, {2}}, {6, {3}}, {4, {4}}, {5, {5}}, {6, {6}}
    };

    // get the range of _Key_s equal to 5
    auto [first, last] = myMap.equal_range(5);

    // the lambda - here used to find the first entry with the _Value_ `X{2}`    
    auto cond = [](auto&& pair) { return pair.second == X{2}; };

    if (auto it = std::find_if(first, last, cond); it != last)
    {
        auto& [k, v] = *it;

        std::cout << k << ' ' << v.m_value << '\n';
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/3fn8vz5eE)

---

If many *Values* may be found, just put the `find_if` in a loop:

```cpp
    for(;(first = std::find_if(first, last, cond)) != last; ++first) {
        auto& [k, v] = *first;

        std::cout << k << ' ' << v.m_value << '\n';
    }
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/6qPse9fKn)

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean that keys in a map are always const, regardless of the key's type?

Comment: @Trazom  You are welcome! Yes, in the standard library containers they are. If you need to change a _Key_ you need to [`extract`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/extract) the node, change the `key()` value in that extracted node and then `std::move` [`insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert) the node again.

Comment: @Trazom The member functions and type definitions for the actual node type may be hard to find. I found it here: [Node handle](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/node_handle)